# Does anybody know if Dell Inspiron 15 3000 support ubuntu?

Tags: hardware-certification

I was looking at

Dell Inspiron 15 3000 Laptop - Intel Core i5

https://www.costco.com/Dell-Inspiron-15-3000-Laptop---Intel-Core-i5.product.100488487.html

Wanted to confirm if all of the components of this model is fully supported in Ubuntu

Comment: Doesn't specify what wireless chipset.  And that will be the most likely part to cause issues.  That said, I've never had issues running multiple distros on any of the Dell hardware I've had... but then again, it has been mostly the business/enterprise line of desktops and laptops, not the home user stuff.

Comment: Dell seems to be the brand that has the most certified laptops as well. Pity they don't actually link to the exact model that somebody can buy. https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop

Comment: https://community.linuxmint.com/hardware/view/27839 - Doesn't link back to the specific model though.